# Updating a c# form while loading a second form

Tags: c#, forms

I am having a problem with updating a textbox inside a form in c#, while loading a second form.

I have two forms in my application. `form1` loads first then it loads `form2`.

When `form2` loads it should update the the `textbox.txt` in `form1` with some text (in this case: `F2:Running`), indicating that it has been loaded.

Any kind of help is appreciated, here's the current code:

```
namespace EditingBox {
    static class Program {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}

namespace EditingBox {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            Form2 F2 = new Form2();
            Form1 F1 = new Form1();

            F2.Show();
            textBox1.Select();
            textBox1.Refresh();
        }

        public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }
    }
}

namespace EditingBox {
    public partial class Form2: Form {
        public Form2() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form1 F1 = new Form1();
            F1.textBox1.Select();
            F1.textBox1.Text = "F2:Running";
            F1.textBox1.Refresh();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Form1 F1 = new Form1();
            F1.textBox1.Select();
            F1.textBox1.Text = "F2:Running";
            F1.textBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the Form1 `this` instance from the original form whenever you create it. Currently:
 `Form1 F1 = new Form1();` is creating a new instance of form1, not the instance which is displayed. Hence all you need to do is add a Form1 form1 to the constructor of form2 and call that constructor whenever you display it:

```
    public Form2(Form1 F1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        F1.textBox1.Select();
        F1.textBox1.Text = "F2:Running";
        F1.textBox1.Refresh();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 F2 = new Form2(this);

        F2.Show();
        textBox1.Select();
        textBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Form1 to Form2 constructor:

```
namespace EditingBox
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 _form1;
        public Form2(Form1 form1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _form1 = form1;
            _form1.textBox1.Select();
            _form1.textBox1.Text = "F2:Running";
            _form1.textBox1.Refresh();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _form1.textBox1.Select();
            _form1.textBox1.Text = "F2:Running";
            _form1.textBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```